# JSON not showing all fields from devise user table in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I try to retrieve the sign_in_count field in the json hash with

```
data = User.where customer: current_user.id
render :json => data
```

It returns only fields: id, name, email, created/updated and customer but not the rest of the table fields. Is this a configuration setting in Devise?

in user.rb i have:

```
devise 
:database_authenticatable,:registerable,:recoverable,:rememberable, 
:trackable, :validatable, :confirmable, :lockable, :zxcvbnable, 
:timeoutable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick.

```
data.as_json(:force_except => Devise::Models::Authenticatable::BLACKLIST_FOR_SERIALIZATION.delete_if{|x| x == :sign_in_count})
```